# looking for Latex editor with good structure tree layout view that can handle verbatim

Tags: editors

I thought to ask if someone knows of a good Latex editor with good side panel that shows the structure of the document.

I have a large document, and many sections and subsections and it is very hard to navigate without a tree like side structure I can use to jump around the document.

I use TexMaker now, which does have this, but the problem is that it gets confused when I add `\section` and `\chapters` in `verbatim` environment (I have many of these, since I use Latex to document things and need to do this in many places).

Hence the structure view/tree becomes very misleading as it is thinking the `\chapter` tag inside a verbatim environment is an actual `\chapter` that belong to the document.

I also tried kyle editor on Linux. Here is a MWE and a screen shot to explain more the problem

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\section{A}

This how to write book style

%----------------
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{some chapter}  %---> This is not a real chapter !
text is here
\end{document}
\end{verbatim}
%----------------

The above was an example.

\section{B}

another section

\end{document}
```

Here is a screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that the layout/tree structure on the left panel is wrong. It should not have picked the \chapter since that is inside verbatim. But the editor have no way of knowing this I suppose. (but it is a Latex editor, should it not know this?)

I also use `Verbatim` environment and not just `verbatim`. Same issue ofcourse.

May be there is a way to configure it to tell the editor to ignore everything inside these environments?

Comment: I would file this as a bug report with [Kyle](http://kile.sourceforge.net/). Of course, you can peruse all the available [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://goo.gl/3f1mL) yourself...

Comment: @Werner thanks for the link. I know about it already. I was hoping someone would already know of one that supports this feature, rather than downloading and trying one by one. I hope it is not too much to ask this.

Comment: Uhm... I think you should send a mail to Pascal Brachet (the TeXmaker developer) or post the error in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) of the oficial site. 

In the other hand, as @Hani Sayegh suggested, you could try with TeXstudio, originally a fork derived from TeXMaker but with a lot of interesting features.

Comment: @Aradnix thanks. I just did that. submitted a bug report https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1183&thanks=1183&ts=1388639685

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/)  is a very good IDE that has this feature, it is also based of TeXmaker so there shouldn't be much of a learning curve.

Comment: it works ! you saved me lots of time. thanks again.

Comment: @Nasser In TeXstudio there are little arrows to the left of a begin, they are used for 'code folding' or basically hiding the code. If you hover over these arrows you should see the vertical lines. From what I remember I did not have to configure anything to get these arrows...do you have them?

Answer (score 4):

[WinEdt 8](http://www.winedt.com/) is able to handle verbatim stuff, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

Note also that there is not any folding node corresponding to `\chapter{some chapter}`.

Additional environments provided by the packages `listings`, `moreverb`, `verbatim`, and `fancyvrb` are supported if you install the add-on [VerbatimPlus](http://www.winedt.org/config/modes/VerbatimPlus.html).

Comment: Thanks. I just downloaded it and tried it. It works with \verbatim OK, however, it does not work with \Verbatim, which I also use. On the other hand, TexStudio knows about both environments. i.e. anything inside \Verbatim and also \verbatim is not added to the the tree view. Maybe there is a way to configure winedit to ignore anything inside \Verbatim as well.

Comment: @Nasser As I said in my answer, you have to install the add-on VerbatimPlus to have that feature for `Verbatim` as well...

Comment: Yes, it works very well. Installed it and now it knows about \Verbatim. Looks like a nice editor, will try it.